# Resize multiple areas with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I've been asked to make an interface where multiple areas will need to be resized at once using jQuery. I've looked at jQuery resizable and can resize one area.

Now that I come to think of it I'm trying to do something similar to JS Bin with the way they resize their columns.

How is this possible? Also, it would be good if the snap points could adjust themselves to a bootstrap grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know how you can do it with `jQuery resizable` but this is actually pretty easy stuff to do with a custom code. Here is a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/te9F8/3/)** that i made with no trouble. Of course it's not 100% ready to go but with a little more work you can use it anyway you like.

The idea is you add a `div` with `0px width` and `1px border` as a seperator between your main `divs`. Define some global `vars` to check current mouse pos and mouse down/up operations and simply with `mousemove` reduce the size of `divs` at the left and rigth side of the seperator accordingly. Check the fiddle. I beleieve it's not too complicated. I can explain anything if you need.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for that answer. I had already thought of just following the position of the mouse but came across articles talking about juqery resizable.
Thanks a lot, great answer